# Nested classes, access private members in inner class

Tags: c++, class, inner-classes

My objective is to create a Book class and also a Bookshelf class. This will be a nested class where Bookshelf is the outer- and Book is in the inner class. I've got it to work if all my data members in my Book class is public. However if it is private like I want to, I don't get it to work because of my `print_bookshelf` function. I will get these errors:

```
test.cpp: In member function 'void Bookshelf::print_bookshelf() const':
test.cpp:40:23: error: 'std::string Bookshelf::Book::title' is private within this context
   40 |             cout << e.title << ", " << e.author << ", " << e.pages << endl;
      |                       ^~~~~
test.cpp:16:20: note: declared private here
   16 |             string title {};
      |                    ^~~~~
test.cpp:40:42: error: 'std::string Bookshelf::Book::author' is private within this context
   40 |             cout << e.title << ", " << e.author << ", " << e.pages << endl;
      |                                          ^~~~~~
test.cpp:17:20: note: declared private here
   17 |             string author {};
      |                    ^~~~~~
test.cpp:40:62: error: 'int Bookshelf::Book::pages' is private within this context
   40 |             cout << e.title << ", " << e.author << ", " << e.pages << endl;
      |                                                              ^~~~~
test.cpp:18:17: note: declared private here
   18 |             int pages {};
      |                 ^~~~~
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bookshelf
{
public:
Bookshelf()
{}

 class Book
    {
    private:
            string title {};
            string author {};
            int pages {};
        
        public:
            Book(string const& t, string const& a, int const p)
                : title{t}, author{a}, pages{p}
            {}

            void print() const
            {
                cout << title << ", " << author << ", " << pages << endl;
            }
        };

    void add_book(Book const& b)
    {
    bookshelf.push_back(b);
    }

    void print_bookshelf () const
    {
        for (auto e : bookshelf)
        {
            cout << e.title << ", " << e.author << ", " << e.pages << endl;
        }
    }

    private:
        vector<Book> bookshelf {};
};

int main()
{
    Bookshelf::Book book_1("Hej", "Me", 100);
    Bookshelf::Book book_2("Yo", "Me", 150);
    Bookshelf bookshelf_1;
    book_1.print();
    bookshelf_1.add_book(book_1);
    bookshelf_1.add_book(book_2);

    bookshelf_1.print_bookshelf();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Private members of a class stay private, no matter if they're defined nested within another class.

Comment: You would have to declare `Bookshelf` as a `friend` of `Book`, but that is not needed if you use [VladfromMoscow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178399/65863).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Outer class access Inner class's private - why forbidden](//stackoverflow.com/q/36008654/)

Answer (score 1):

Just change this function

```
void print_bookshelf () const
{
    for (auto e : bookshelf)
    {
        cout << e.title << ", " << e.author << ", " << e.pages << endl;
    }
}
```

the following way

```
void print_bookshelf () const
{
    for ( const auto &e : bookshelf )
    {
       e.print();
    }
}
```

You will avoid code duplication and use the public interface of the class  Book.

Comment: Hey Vlad! Thank you for your amazing solution! 

However what if I want to remove a book? I want to remove the book once some enters the title they want removed

I want to implement a function like this: void remove_book (title const& t) {}; but title is a private data member

Comment: @KevlarProgramming Add to the class Book a constant public member function that returns title.

Comment: But then I cant use "title" as a parameter. If I do "string get_title() {return title;", how would I used my returned string as a parameter to my remove_book function?

Comment: @KevlarProgramming  You can use as an argument of your function remove_book. Why not?

Comment: I dont really know how that would be implemented. I am returning a string from my get_title. How do I take in THAT particular string as a parameter in my remove_book function?

Comment: @KevlarProgramming As an argument you can use any string. You will use the function get_title to compare the used argument with  titles of elements in the vector and if such an element exists you can remove it from the vector.